# Which hostings are compatible with Winsock and C ++

Tags: c++, hosting, winsock2

I use **winsock2** for making tcp server. I have made a little **client-server** program which is a chatting system.I tested my code on my machine and now i want to make it public, I mean to host my code on real server but i dont know **which hosting services are suitable** for my program.
What can you advice?

Comment: You can't run your server app on most hosting services, that is simply not how they work. Unless you rewrite your system to work over an HTTP server, you are better off just running your own server machine connected to the Internet and maybe register a domain to point at it. Otherwise, look into implementing peer-2-peer technologies into your system so that your client apps talk to each other directly and don't need a centralized server at all

Comment: Thanks for your comment , it didn't solve my problem but helped to understand what i have to do